# Algorithm or data structure for broadcast messages in 3D

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, network-programming

Let's say some threads produce data and every piece of data has associated 3D coordinate. And other threads consumes these data and every consumer thread has cubic volume of interest described by center and "radius" (size of the cube). Consumer threads can update their cube of interest parameter (like move it) from time to time. Every piece of data is broadcasted - a copy of it should be received by every thread which has cube of interest which includes this coordinate.

What multi-threaded data structure can be used for this with the best performance? I am using C++, but generic algorithm pointer is fine too.

Bonus: it would be nice if an algorithm will have possibility to generalize to multiple network nodes (some nodes produce data and some consumes with the same rules as threads).

Extra information: there are more consumers than producers, there are much more data broadcasts than cube of interest changes (cube size changes are very rare, but moving is quite common event). It's okay if consumer will start receiving data from the new cube of interest after some delay after changing it (but before that it should continue receive data from the previous cube).

Comment: You might benefit from using space partitioning data structures such as octree or a k-d tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree to narrow down the candidate nodes to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Your terminology is problematic. A cube by definition does not have a radius; a sphere does. A broadcast by definition is received by everyone, it is not received only by those who are interested; a multicast is.</sup>

I have encountered this problem in the development of an MMORPG. The approach taken in the development of that MMORPG was a bit wacky, but in the decade that followed my thinking has evolved so I have a much better idea of how to go about it now.

The solution is a bit involved, but it does not require any advanced notions like space partitioning, and it is reusable for all kinds of information that the consumers will inevitably need besides just 3D coordinates. Furthermore, it is reusable for entirely different projects.

We begin by building a light-weight data modelling framework which allows us to describe, instantiate, and manipulate finite, self-contained sets of inter-related ***observable*** data known as "Entities" ***in memory*** and perform various operations on them in an application-agnostic way.

- Description can be done in simple object-relational terms. ("Object-relational" means relational with inheritance.)
- Instantiation means that given a schema, the framework creates a container (an "EntitySpace") to hold, during runtime, instances of entities described by the schema.
- Manipulation means being able to read and write properties of those entities.
- Self-contained means that although an entity may contain a property which is a reference to another entity, the other entity must reside within the same EntitySpace.
- Observable means that when the value of a property changes, a notification is issued by the EntitySpace, telling us which property of which entity has changed. Anyone can register for notifications from an EntitySpace, and receives ***all of them***.

Once you have such a framework, you can build lots of useful functionality around it in an entirely application-agnostic way. For example:

- Serialization: you can serialize and de-serialize an EntitySpace to and from markup.
- Filtering: you can create a special kind of EntitySpace which does not contain storage, and instead acts as a view into a subset of another EntitySpace, filtering entities based on the values of certain properties.
- Mirroring: You can keep an EntitySpace in sync with another, by responding to each property-changed notification from one and applying the change to the other, and vice versa.
- Remoting: You can interject a transport layer between the two mirrored parts, thus keeping them mirrored while they reside on different threads or on different physical machines.

Every node in the network must have a corresponding "agent" object running inside every node that it needs data from. If you have a centralized architecture, (and I will continue under this hypothesis,) this means that within the server you will have one agent object for each client connected to that server. The agent represents the client, so the fact that the client is remote becomes irrelevant. The agent is only responsible for filtering and sending data to the client that it represents, so multi-threading becomes irrelevant, too.

An agent registers for notifications from the server's EntitySpace and filters them based on whatever criteria you choose. One such criterion for an Entity which contains a 3D-coordinate property can be whether that 3D-coordinate is within the client's area of interest. The center-of-sphere-and-radius approach will work, the center-of-cube-and-size approach will probably work even better. (No need for calculating a square.)